# Rateable can't be blank(mongoid-letsrate,Mongoid)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, devise

When I try create new `User(devise)` I get this error:

```
Rateable can't be blank(mongoid-letsrate,Mongoid)
Mongoid::Errors::Validations:
   message:
     Validation of User failed.
   summary:
     The following errors were found: Rateable can't be blank
   resolution:
     Try persisting the document with valid data or remove the validations.
```

**My model User:**

```
# User
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Letsrate
   letsrate_rater
end
```

**My model Book:**

```
# Book
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Letsrate
  letsrate_rateable
end
```

Comment: You create user with `User(devise)`? What is `letsrate_rater` and `letsrate_rateable` ? Where are they defined?

Comment: https://github.com/malagant/mongoid-letsrate